# Google sheets: Subsidiaries and invoices and dependent dynamic dropdown lists

Tags: validation, google-sheets, invoice

I'm trying to solve an issue for listing invoices of different subsidiaries (subs) on google sheets. I am going to use two different sheets for this. These will be called Sheet1 and Sheet2.

Now for the sake of the problem, imagine there are three different subs (A,B and C).
Each sub has its own unique invoice tag: A has A-001, A-002, etc; B has B-001, B-002, etc; and C has C-001, C-002, etc.  These unique invoice tags are listed in Sheet2 under their respective sub heading (A,B or C) and are in a sorted range.

Imagine in Sheet 1, there is column A and B. Column A will contain a dropdown to select one sub; for example, sub A. Now what I want in column B, is another dropdown that only consists of invoices related to sub A (if sub B is selected I want the dropdown in column B to only contain a B-XXX invoice).

So in short, I want the user to first select a specific sub from a dropdown list and in the next column the user only has to view the invoices related to that specific sub in a dropdown list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls, take a copy (sorry this sample is in French, nevertheless you will be able to understand the formulas and the place of them) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IDifehV68cEGlI1pqpvNLEnReZRLnyiZf-4ipFl-E3s/copy
in B2 of choice, the validation is (be carefull of the $)

```
=Lists!$F2:$Z2
```

in F2 of Lists, according to your choice in A2, the list of data available is

```
=iferror(transpose(OFFSET(A$2:A,,MATCH(Choice!A2,$1:$1,0)-1)),"Choisir une matière")
```

Answer (score 2):

I do this in many of my projects and it is rather straightforward. I used Data/Validation and the QUERY() function. In my example I have three tabs, one for the dropdowns and one each for subs and invoices as follows:

[image]

Here is the subs tab:

[image]

Here is the invoices tab, note I suggest you follow adding the Sub_Code column which in SQL language is the foreign key to link the two tables:

[image]

This is the data validation for cell A2 on the Dropdown tab:

[image]

This is the QUERY() function for cell B2 on the Dropdown tab:

```
=query(Invoices!A1:B, "select A where B='"&A2&"' LABEL A ''", TRUE)
```

Here is a link to my example, feel free to make a copy:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qbLOjTdzISICTKyUp_jK6gZbQCt-OwtDYYy3HNJygeE/edit#gid=795322028